# Writing a serializer for Gson using Java 8

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, java-8

I have a own class called `MyDate` and want to write a serializer of it for Gson. This code works:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyDate.class, new JsonSerializer<MyDate>() {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(MyDate date, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(date.toString());
    }
});
```

However I want to use the power of Java 8 and therefore tried

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyDate.class, (date, typeOfSrc, context) ->new JsonPrimitive(date.toString()));
```

But here eclipse tells me

> The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

What's wrong about that Java 8 code?

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with Java 8? `builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyDate.class, (JsonSerializer<MyDate>) (date, typeOfSrc, context) -> new JsonPrimitive(date.toString()));` works for me

Comment: @AlexisC. That works because of the cast (also another solution).

Comment: @Radiodef I'm saying that because the OP shouldn't have this error message. With javac, I get `incompatible types: Object is not a functional interface`. Which makes sense, so maybe it's ECJ messages that are a bit misleading (which wouldn't surprise me) ;-)... It's true that the target type is not a functional interface, but javac is a bit more precise there.

Comment: ... but nevermind. My first comment was a bit stupid, if the OP had this error message, then he's obviously compiling with Java 8 :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to replace an anonymous class with a lambda, the parameter must be a **Single Method Interface** (SMI).

This is an `interface` with a **single `abstract` method**.

[`GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdaper`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) takes an `Object` as the second argument.

You need to first *assign* your lambda then pass in the method:

```
final JsonSerializer<MyDate> serializer = (date, typeOfSrc, context) -> new JsonPrimitive(date.toString());

builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyDate.class, serializer);
```

This way you tell compiler which SMI you would like to implement.

Comment: Thanks. There is a semicolon missing in the end of the first line. I'm not allowed to make such small edits.